# Efficiently verifying the parameters that are passed inside a method

Tags: c#, validation, methods

I have a method which takes an `OrderedSet` **X** of objects of type `A`, and an `OrderedSet` **Y** of `OrderedSets` of objects of type B. (*Nested*)

This method then returns a new `OrderedSet` **Z** of `Edges` based on the two sets given.

Basically, I give the method two sets, and the method gives me back a *connection* much like the mathematical definition of a function.

So if I want to make a bijective connection, I would have to ensure that both sets have equal size, and I do not want null objects to be present anywhere.

The problem is, these sets are going to be arbitrarily large, and what I would like to do is this :

- Ensure that nothing in these sets will ever be null
- Ensure that every set has the required size

What I have done to obtain what I want :

- I implemented the `OrderedSet` as a HashSet with extra properties, and I simply check for null elements using Contains which is O(1) (I am not entirely sure if this is a good solution)
- `OrderedSet` refuses to add `null` objects, but this does not change the possibility of changing the elements within the set *once they are added*, and setting them to null this way
- I tried taking the *easy way out* and nested the contents of the method in a try-catch, so if something goes wrong I simply catch the error and move on, rather than having to first validate all the data passed (Assume the sets might be very huge, there is no limitation on their size) *The issue with this is that it might fail at the very end, wasting computation time*
- I also tried making a brute force check, so basically checking every set for nulls, including the sets within the second parameter, and also checking every single set for its correct size to be expected. This would work in theory, but I feel is impractical and surely there could be a more clever solution to this problem.

What I have considered :

- I have looked into Contracts, but [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181411/Code-Contract-Performance-Analysis) shows a significant (in my opinion) decrease in performance, although it does accomplish what I am looking for (*Yet still in a hacky sort of way*)
- I have read about *non-nullable* reference types that are supposed to come out in C# 8.0, which might solve the problem of having to check for null elements, but I would still be left with the issue of having to check for all the sizes of the sets involved, each time I want to make a new connection.

My goal :
To have a readable, yet efficient solution to parameter validation.
Thank you for your time, please feel free to correct me if I have said something that is not quite correct.

Comment: `hashsetInstance.Any(x => x == null)` is not that impractical i think. Anyway if you refuse to add nulls to your hashset I can not think of a way to get one into it.

Comment: @thehennyy Maybe I am not thinking straight, but isn't this possible?
set[i] = null;

Comment: Yeah, if you refuse to add `null` objects, how would there be a possibility to setting them `null` after they're added? -- if you have `var item = new Thing(); yourSet.Add(item); item = null;` then `yourSet` will still have a (reference to) a valid instance of `Thing`. I don't see a way how you could ever have a `null` reference there.

Comment: Provide an indexer method that refuses to take `null`.

Comment: @Threnody - only if you allow the indexer set to accept `null`.

Comment: Both of you are right! It did not occur to me to enforce it in the indexer as well. :D